# Resolve EL expressions programmatically on Seam managed beans

Tags: java, jsf, seam

How can we resolve JSF EL expressions programmatically on Seam managed beans? I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
private String resolveExpression(String expression){

        if(expression == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        javax.faces.context.FacesContext facesCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Application app = facesCtx.getApplication();

        try 
        {
            // Here we bind a value expression into the item, 
            // so it can dynamically change its language
            ELContext elCtx = facesCtx.getELContext();
            ExpressionFactory ef = app.getExpressionFactory();
            ValueExpression ve = ef.createValueExpression(elCtx, expression, String.class);

            return (String) ve.getValue(elCtx);
        } 
        catch (ELException ex) {
        }

        return expression;
    }
```

In my application I have a bean named `User` that in session scope of Seam sits and this bean has a property `name`. The EL expression is `#{usr.name}`, but this expression returns empty while it works fine in a Facelet file.

Comment: Have you tried #{usr.username}?

Comment: sorry 'name' not 'username' :D

Comment: Maybe you should not just eliminate the `ELException` here. Try to log that exception, maybe that gives you some kind of a hint.

Comment: I logged this exception as you suggest but there's no exception here :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seam provides two utility components for dealing with EL expressions: `Expressions` and `Interpolator`.

For your particular use case, I believe `Interpolator` is the correct choice, since you don't really need a valid `ValueExpression`. `Interpolator` parses the whole string for EL expressions and converts all of them to their evaluated values.

Beware that `Interpolator#interpolate()` also accepts arguments (see the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/api/org/jboss/seam/core/Interpolator.html)).

Example:

```
@Name("bean")
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
class MyBean {
     ...

     public String getValue() {
          return value;
     }

     ...
}

@Name("otherBean")
@Scope(ScopeType.EVENT)
class MyBean {
     ...

     public String getInterpolatedValue() {
          return Interpolator.instance().interpolate("#{bean.value}");
     }

     ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seam provided an Expressions object. I'm using this one for the moment and it works well. Put your objects into the event context and call:

Expressions.instance().createValueExpression(string).getValue()

Updated : the class is called expressions

Comment: Hi. Are you sure that you are accessing a variable that is existing? If you get an empty result it normaly means somethingis resolving to null. Try somethig simple like createValueExpression("#{'hello'}").getValue()  Since hello is defined as a string in this expression (with the single quotes) this has to return hello.    I use this approach to create emails from templates and i can use anyhing that is available at the time of creation. Factories. Components. Unwrap. Variables in any contexts.

Comment: I tried to logout and login again with the same user and I got this value, but when I login again with other user I got information of previous user. :( :(

Comment: I also print out the bean to log file and in the first time it displays nothing. I login the second time, it displays the details of that bean. :( :(